# Div no tamanho do body

Tags: html5, css3

Tenho uma div que fica no meu rodapé da pagina, parecido com um footer, o problema e que esta div esta dentro de outras divs, eu queria que ela ficasse com o tamanho exato do meu body, sem mexer no html somente no css.
Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, coloque seu código para que possamos te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, para poder ter esse resultado uma vez que as divs anteriores interferem no width da div desejada podes retirar da posição estática(a usada normalmente) para absoluta e posiciona-la. ex:

```
<style>
div#inner-div{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
bottom : 0px;
}
<style>
```

Acredito que possa resolver o problema de não estar com o tamanho do body, mas existem algumas precauções que deves levar em conta:

1. Se a div que pretender colocar com tamanho do body tiver conteúdo
   acima e a baixo, ira sair do espaço qual estava e se quiseres que
   esteja no mesmo local de antes deveras dar esse espaço através das
   areas que la ficaram, ou usar position relative
2. Poderas position relative caso o pai(selector) antecedente tenha
   position absolute

Comment: Acredito que quando ele diz querer a div do tamanho do body, ele quis dizer altura e não largura.

Comment: Era exatamente isto, ajustar a largura, a altura vai se auto ajustar com o conteúdo que vou colocar dentro dela, muito obrigado.